# 3D Autoencoder has low error but poor results when plotting

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, autoencoder

I am making an auto-encoder to reduce the dimensionality of lung CT scans (3D).

The input is 176(patients) x 30(slices) x 256 x 256 x 1. While it achieves a loss of 0.1233 (binary_crossentropy), when I plot the predictions it makes on the training set they don't look very good. Do you have any suggestions about how to fix this? (is it a matter of training for longer?).

Thank you :)
(I am new to ML)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv3D, Conv3DTranspose, MaxPooling3D, UpSampling3D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from sys import getsizeof
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
import os 
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

# Creating the model
input_img = Input(shape=(32,256,256,1))

x = Conv3D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (5,5,5), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(4, 4, 4), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv3D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv3D(filters = 8, kernel_size = (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(4, 4, 4), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv3D(filters = 8, kernel_size = (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling3D((4,4,4))(x)
x = Conv3D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((2,2,2))(x)
x = Conv3D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (5,5,5), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling3D((4,4,4))(x)
decoded = Conv3D(filters = 1, kernel_size = (5,5,5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

x_train = np.load('D:\\nparr\\npstack_l.npy')
x_train = x_train.astype('float16') / 255
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 32, 256, 256))

#print(x_train.nbytes)
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=15, batch_size = 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')

# Predict from training set and plot
decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(x_train[0:4].reshape(2,32,256,256,1))
n = 4
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
    # display original
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_train[i][15].reshape(256, 256))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i][15].reshape(256, 256))
    plt.gray()
    #print(decoded_imgs[0][15])
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[autoencoder output on subsection of training set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pDl0.png)

Answer (score 0):

A better way of knowing if your training is working when using binary is to use accuracy.
Try changing:

```
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

to

```
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta',loss='binary_crossentropy', metric=['binary_accuracy']
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful. Its converging at around 93% which isn't great since most of the image is black background, maybe the convolution kernels are too large?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using Dense layers between?

Comment: Not really, I did try it and the model did worse. Is there some advantage to having a dense layer?